# How do I make the square and circles show up at the same time in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a game where there are a bunch of falling circles and the player(the square) needs to avoid them. I have managed to get the controls of the player and all of the falling circles but when I press play all I see are the falling circles and no square. The only time the square shows is when I press the arrow keys. How can I make the square and circles show up at the same time?

```
 import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import os
import random
import math
import sys
import time

white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
gravity = 10
size =10
height = 500
width =600
varHeigth = height
ballNum = 5
eBall = []
apGame = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("AP Project")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):

  def __init__(self):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(apGame,red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))
    self.dist = 10

  def handle_keys(self):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
      if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit();
        exit()
      elif e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        key = e.key
        if key == pygame.K_LEFT:
          self.draw_rect(-1, 0)
        elif key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
          self.draw_rect(1, 0)
        elif key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
          pygame.quit();
          exit()

  def draw_rect(self, x, y):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    '''apGame.fill(black)'''
    self.rect = self.rect.move(x * self.dist, y * self.dist);
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red , self.rect)
    pygame.display.update()


  def draw(self,surface):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))


move_x = 300
move_y = 400
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
'''apGame.fill(black)'''
player.draw(apGame)
pygame.display.update()

for q in range(ballNum):
  x = random.randrange(0, width)
  y = random.randrange(0, varHeigth)
  eBall.append([x, y])

while True:
#I think this is where my problem is
  apGame.fill(black)
  player.handle_keys()

  for i in range(len(eBall)):

    pygame.draw.circle(apGame, blue, eBall[i], size)

    eBall[i][1] += 5

    if eBall[i][1] > height:

        y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
        eBall[i][1] = y

        x = random.randrange(0, width)
        eBall[i][0] = x


  pygame.display.flip()
  clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you insert a line :

```
player.draw_rect (0, 0)
```

just above

```
pygame.display.flip ()
```

then your square will show up.
I would recommend using :

```
pygame.key.get_pressed ()
```

instead of :

```
pygame.KEYDOWN
```

so that your player will keep moving as long as the key is being held down instead of having to press and release the left or right keys over and over.

**Edit :**
In response to OPs question in comments, here is working code :

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import random

white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
gravity = 10
size =10
height = 500
width =600
varHeigth = height
ballNum = 5
eBall = []
apGame = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("AP Project")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(object):

  def __init__(self):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(apGame,red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))
    self.dist = 10

  def handle_keys(self):
    for e in pygame.event.get():
      if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit();
        exit()
    key = pygame.key.get_pressed ()
    if key [pygame.K_LEFT]:
      self.draw_rect(-1, 0)
    elif key [pygame.K_RIGHT]:
      self.draw_rect(1, 0)
    elif key [pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
      pygame.quit();
      exit()
    else :
      self.draw_rect (0, 0)

  def draw_rect(self, x, y):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    self.rect = self.rect.move(x * self.dist, y * self.dist);
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red , self.rect)

  def draw(self,surface):
    red = (255, 0, 0)
    move_x = 300
    move_y = 400
    pygame.draw.rect(apGame, red, (move_x, move_y, 10, 10))


move_x = 300
move_y = 400
red = (255, 0, 0)
black = (0, 0, 0)
player = Player()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
'''apGame.fill(black)'''
player.draw(apGame)
pygame.display.update()

for q in range(ballNum):
  x = random.randrange(0, width)
  y = random.randrange(0, varHeigth)
  eBall.append([x, y])

while True:
  apGame.fill(black)
  for i in range(len(eBall)):
    pygame.draw.circle(apGame, blue, eBall[i], size)
    eBall[i][1] += 5
    if eBall[i][1] > height:
        y = random.randrange(-50, -10)
        eBall[i][1] = y
        x = random.randrange(0, width)
        eBall[i][0] = x

  player.handle_keys ()
  pygame.display.flip()
  clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: The player is showing but I can't get the player to move. I try using your pygame.key.get_pressed() but I can't make it to work. Do you have any examples or sources to look at?